# Hint for the hover state in both web and mobile versions

Tags: mobile, web, hover, hints

I am designing a portfolio page which showcases a list of photographs. Below are is wireframe and my main doubts.

[image]

**Doubts:**

- How will the user know the portfolio items have a description on the `hover` states? Do I need to put some kind of hint?
- Mobile devices don't have the mouse over concept. So how can I
  represent the same idea (To replace the hover state) in the mobile
  design?

Comment: hover effects on touch screen is a much discussed topic. +1 for that question. Try [this link](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/hover-effect-on-touch-devices) and [this link.](http://www.prowebdesign.ro/how-to-deal-with-hover-on-touch-screen-devices/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Suggestion shown below.

**On Desktop**

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnbOUB.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

**On Mobile**

User tend to scroll more on mobile devices especially if you  are designing for a blog/static site. You probably want to show everything instead of hiding and making user tap on individual photos. I would say just place a truncated description below the photo. The user can click to read more if they are interested.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWrsd6.png)</sup>

**